# Get URL to return back to page

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

I have a website which uses a multi-step Contour form. When the user clicks "Next" i would like to get the URL so they can return back to the same step if they have not completed the form.

At present if the page URL is http://currentsite.com/questionnaire/qa1.aspx (qa1.aspx is the page that holds the Contour form) it returns back to the same step, if i close my browser and navigate back to the samem page.

My concern here is if the user deletes their cookies this would mean they cant return to the form again by browsing to the same page.

So how could i create the URL to return the user back to the step/page on a partially submitted form?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has to log in, I would recommend that you store the form information in a database, associated with their login information.

Comment: No user logs in (this would be an open site). I save the form during partial submit (i.e. when you click next on the form).... so im looking for a way to retrieve the URL so the user could have the same experience as if the cookie had not been deleted.

Comment: But your URL contains no information about the data in the form, looking at it?

Comment: Thats correct. What im asking is, the cookie is being used to get the data and display it i would think. So the cookie must be holding the Record ID, that record ID is being passed into Contour somehow to get the data. If you know how then perhaps i could look at the way its constructed then make a few tweaks?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how contour works to do that.